# Create random trainable indices to build two 2_D tensor from one 2_D tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I'm trying to create two tensors with shape **shape=(30, 4200)** from one tensor ***AAA*** with shape=(30, 4201)and type= float32.

This error will appear again after running the code with several different changes.

How do I select the correct tensor shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would use `tf.gather_nd` for your case:

```
# If V1_emb and V2_emb have different shapes you need to take the shape of each one
s = tf.shape(V1, out_type=V1_emb.dtype)
batch_idx = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(s[0]), 1), [1, s[1]])
V1 = tf.gather_nd(params=AAA, indices=tf.stack([batch_idx, V1_emb], axis=-1))
V2 = tf.gather_nd(params=AAA, indices=tf.stack([batch_idx, V2_emb], axis=-1))
```

Comment: I can guarantee you that `V1_emb` will _not_ be trained, as integer variables cannot be trained. For a variable to be trainable, it must be floating point type and all the operations from that variable to the loss value must be floating point and differentiable (here it is integer and the variable is used in `tf.gather_nd`, which is not a differentiable operation for the indices).